# First use of litte $o_p$ (little $o$ in probability) notation?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, notation, probability

I have a follow up question from my previous question on math.SE, where I asked about the [First use of little $o$ notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148219/first-use-of-little-o-notation) - for those who want to check - the answer goes back to Landau ($1909$), this could really be one of the earliest occurrences (the definition is motivated by the big $O$ notation and there is no reference to any other work, so it seems genuin).

Now I wonder when the slightly different notation of [$o_p(\cdot)$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation#Small_O:_convergence_in_probability) was first introduced. Clearly later but unfortunately there is no historically reference on Wikipedia. Does anyone have a clue or reference where I should look into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Earliest use of mathematical symbols](http://jeff560.tripod.com/stat.html):

> The convergence in probability symbol *plim* was introduced by H. B. Mann and A. Wald "On Stochastic Limit and Order Relationships," Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 14, (1943), 217-226. The stochastic order symbols $O_p$ and $o_p$, modelled on the $O$ and $o$, or Landau symbols, were introduced in the same paper.